# wp_enqueue_style $dep argument does nothing?

Tags: themes

I'm trying to make a child theme of the twentyseventeen theme.  I started by making a style.css with the content:

```
/*
Theme Name: John Tries This
Template: twentyseventeen
*/
```

I then made this functions.php

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyseventeen-style' for the Twenty Seventeen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css'
//        ,array( $parent_style )
    );
}
```

What I don't understand is the 3rd argument of wp_enqueue_style.   You see that I have it commented out.  My web page shows all my parent styles and templates regardless of whether or not I comment out the `,array($parent_style)`.

So what exactly does this 3rd argument do?  The wordpress documentation says it is a list of dependencies.  Why should I provide dependencies?  What behaviour will it alter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *3rd* argument of `wp_enqueue_style` means when enqueuing this stylesheet make sure it is after the list of dependencies.

In your case, prior to enqueueing the `child-style` WordPress make sure that `parent-style` is enqueued first.

Even though the enqueued statements are in the correct order:

```
wp_enqueue_style('parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style('child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
```

There will be an instance where `child-style` is enqueued first before the `parent-style`. So, to make sure that the order of the enqueued stylesheets are correct you need to supply the third argument, which is a list of dependencies.